# How to create an interpolated colormap or color palette from two colors?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure, colorbar

I'd like to create a color palette between two colors. For instance between **Blue** and **Red** with 20 or 50 instances.

How can this be achieved in Matlab R2014b?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use any kind of interpolation (e.g. [**`interp1`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)) to create your own custom [**colormap**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) between two colors or multiple colors. A colormap is basically a 3-column matrix with RGB-values. In your case its pretty simple, as you just need **red** with `[1 0 0]` and **blue** `[0 0 1]` and linearly interpolated in between. [**`linspace`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) is therefore the best choice.

```
n = 50;               %// number of colors

R = linspace(1,0,n);  %// Red from 1 to 0
B = linspace(0,1,n);  %// Blue from 0 to 1
G = zeros(size(R));   %// Green all zero

colormap( [R(:), G(:), B(:)] );  %// create colormap

%// some example figure
figure(1)
surf(peaks)
colorbar
```

[image]

Note that you could also use the the colormap GUI by typing `colormapeditor`.

---

Alternative you can also use [**2D-interpolation**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html):

```
n = 50;                %// number of colors

cmap(1,:) = [1 0 0];   %// color first row - red
cmap(2,:) = [0 1 0];   %// color 25th row - green
cmap(3,:) = [0 0 1];   %// color 50th row - blue

[X,Y] = meshgrid([1:3],[1:50]);  %// mesh of indices

cmap = interp2(X([1,25,50],:),Y([1,25,50],:),cmap,X,Y); %// interpolate colormap
colormap(cmap) %// set color map

%// some example figure
figure(1)
surf(peaks)
colorbar
```

[image]

---

And just another example using **spline-interpolation** to get wider areas of blue and red:

```
n = 50;                %// number of colors

v = [0,0,0.1,0.5,0.9,1,1];
x = [-5*n,0, 0.45*n, 0.5*n, 0.55*n, n, 5*n]; 
xq = linspace(1,n,n);
vq = interp1(x,v,xq,'spline');
vq = vq - min(vq);
vq = vq./max(vq);

B = vq;  %// Blue from 0 to 1 with spline shape
R = fliplr(B);  %// Red as Blue but mirrored
G = zeros(size(R));   %// Green all zero

colormap( [R(:), G(:), B(:)] );  %// create colormap

%// some example figure
figure(1)
surf(peaks)
colorbar
```

[image]

---

Or use any mathematical function you want:

```
n = 50;                %// number of colors

t = linspace(0,4*pi,50);

B = sin(t)*0.5 + 0.5;  %// Blue from 0 to 1 as sine
R = cos(t)*0.5 + 0.5;  %// Red from 0 to 1 as cosine
G = zeros(size(R));   %// Green all zero

colormap( [R(:), G(:), B(:)] );  %// create colormap

%// some example figure
figure(1)
surf(peaks)
colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I got your idea.

Comment: Is there a way to set the colormap so zero is always white? I'm looking to go from positive red to negative blue, but I need the regions close to zero to be white. Thanks!

Comment: @WnGatRC456 whats wrong with my example to "2D-interpolation" and exchanging green with white? If that does not help you, please ask a new question.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I was just asking if it was possible to make it so the range always centered at 0. I actually took your script and just used `caxis` to make the colormap and colorbar symmetric about 0.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 alright, Now I understand your question entirely. `caxis` is a good choice, if your value distribution is kind of symmetrical. If not, you can create an asymmetrical colormap. My example shows three colors, you can also add more colors to change the position of the transitions zones. It is also possible to truncate the resulting colormap to adjust the position of the zero value.